# Is it possible to make csv file using records from KAFKA STREAMS within a time frame?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to send data records from Kafka topic using Kafka Streams using SCALA. After each 100 record, it should make a csv. Is it possible without use of Kafka connect??

UPDATE : I'm able to make csv with `forEach` processor. I'm creating a listBuffer which stores 100 records and when it reaches 100 records, it makes a csv.
And if there are more than 100 records (say 142 records) it should make csv with remaining 42 records if no more records are arriving in a time frame of 4 seconds. But inactive time cannot be calculated as `foreach` processor is inactive after all the records have been processed. Is there any way to check whether there the next record is empty so that I can make csv with the remaining records?? OR is there a way to find the inactive period inside the `foreach` processor??
`writeToCsvFile` is a separate function to write records to csv.

I am posting the code here :

```
  var t :Long = System.currentTimeMillis()

  kStream.foreach((key, value) => {

    recordFields = value.split(",")
    listOfRecords += recordFields

      if ((listOfRecords.size >= 100 || System.currentTimeMillis()-t >= 4000)) {
        t = System.currentTimeMillis()
        size = listOfRecords.size
        fileNameVariable = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd_HH-mm-ss").format(Calendar.getInstance.getTime)
        fileName = f"output/${fileNameVariable}_${System.currentTimeMillis()}${size}_records.csv"
        writeToCsvFile(fileName, listOfRecords)
        listOfRecords.clear()
      }
  })
```

Comment: Hi Anish, welcome to StackOverflow! A few questions: What system is reading the CSV? Can't it just read from the Kafka topic directly? Why don't you want to use Kafka Connect?

Comment: What is stopping you from using a `forEach` action to open a file and write 100 records to it?

Comment: hi @RobinMoffatt HDFS is reading from the topic. But need to make csv for some other reason.

Comment: hi @OneCricketeer Thank you very much for your suggestion. It helped. I'm new to Kafka Streams and thanks for help.

Comment: hi @OneCricketeer I have updated my question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. 1) HDFS doesn't read Kafka data 2) Kafka Connect `FileStreamSink` should be able to do what you want. Or HDFS Sink if that's where you want data to go. 3) Sounds like you need to detect when the buffer is full, then flush it, then keep reading more data into it. You'll need to show code if you want more help with that

Comment: @OneCricketeer hi, I've added the code.

Comment: Thanks. I don't immediately see anything wrong with this. Obviously, you wont create a file until one of the two conditions hold, **but** your timestamp check will never happen if there are no more records to consume, so `forEach` is the wrong solution, compared to a regular consumer. I'm mostly confused why you want to do it this way when there are other purpose-built solutions to this outside of Kafka Streams. For example, the HDFS (2) sink connector allows you to set `flush.size=100`, and a timestamp rotation policy for writing files

Comment: @OneCricketeer So what you conclude is that there is no way to check for the time elapsed (and if it is greater than ,say 4sec ) and send the remaining records in listBuffer to  make a CSV??

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible, I was saying that the condition wouldn't be checked if there are no records being consumed. You'd need a separate thread that checks how much time has elapsed, and flushes the file (while pausing the consumer) rather than put that in a stream's foreach loop

Comment: @OneCricketeer But that thread won't be able to measure the time the records are not consumed. It measures time elapsed randomly... Right?? If not, can you please give a code solution??

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the code. I will try and convert the code to Scala and check the results.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the original question, yes, it is possible, assuming that the topic has exactly a multiple of the amount of lines in the file you want to limit by. E.g. You want to write files of 100 lines, then if you consume only 42 records, then there will be no file.

You've then added additional constraints to the problem, such as a timer. If there are no records to consume, then the time condition is not checked, and so the file will also not be written.

The only way to check the "next record is empty" is to use a regular `Consumer` and check the size of the iterator returned by `poll()`

---

If you must use Kafka Streams, one workaround would be to define a background thread.

```java
public class FileWriterTask<T> implements Runnable {
  private final List<T> buffer = new ArrayList<>(100);
  private long lastFlush = System.currentTimeMillis();

  // TODO: Constructor
  
  public void add(T t) { buffer.add(t); }

  public void flush(long flushTime) {
    writeToCsv(buffer);
    buffer.clear();
    lastFlush = flushTime;
  }

  AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(true);

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (running.get()) {
        long now = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
        if (buffer.size() >= 100 || (now - lastFlush) >= 4000) {
          flush(now);
        } 
        // NOTE: Need to make sure the consumer poll loop allows for one second plus any time it takes to create and write to a file
        Thread.sleep(1000); 
    }
  }
}
```

Then pass that thread to the stream action... Code untested and my Scala is weak, so using Java, but should get the point across.

```java
final Thread t = new Thread(new FileWriterTask<String>());
t.start();
kStream.foreach((key, value) => { 
    recordFields = value.split(",")
    recordFields.foreach(t::add);
});

// TODO: add shutdown hook
// t.running.set(false);
```

Note that you might need to write it differently like so (Java) in order for the closure of the thread to be correct... The class might need extracted too.

```java
kStream.foreach((key, value) -> new ForeachAction { 
  
    final Thread t = new Thread(new FileWriterTask<String>());

    public FoeachAction() {
       t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(? k, String value) { // not sure what your key type is
        recordFields = value.split(",")
        recordFields.foreach(t::add);
    }
    
});
```